# DOMException error was thrown on calling cavas.toDataUrl()

Tags: fabricjs

When we call "canvas.toDataURL('image/png')" after some changes (such as drag and move an image in the canvas by fabricjs), an exception was thrown:

```
The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0
```

What is this mean? Obviously our canvas element has its own width and height, and none of them is 0.

Comment: can you post a fiddle or snippet showing the issue?

Comment: well, it's a quite complicated page, i can not reproduce it by a snippet, but i traced this error in debug mode, and was sure it caused by canvas.toDataURL('image/png').

Comment: Well, i know, i really set an image height to 0 in code, sorry.